# Updating Account Object in Salesforce with Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, contentdocumentlink

I'm new to apex and trying to figure out how I can update a custom field on the Account object when a note is added.  This is what I have for a trigger but the field isn't updating.  I am not getting any errors.

```
trigger UpdateAccountField on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : Trigger.new) {
        if (cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == Account.sObjectType && cdl.ContentDocument.FileType == 'SNOTE') {
            accountIds.add(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
        }
    }

    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Last_Note_Date__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds];

    for (Account acc : accountsToUpdate) {
        acc.Last_Note_Date__c = date.today();
    }

    update accountsToUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this condition here: `cdl.ContentDocument.FileType == 'SNOTE'`. Parent and child relationships are not automatically included in `Trigger.old` or `Trigger.new`, so you must query for them.

```
Map<Id, ContentDocument> documents = new Map<Id, ContentDocument>();
ContentDocumentLink[] linksToCheck = new ContentDocumentLink[0];
Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();

// Check for links to accounts
for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: Trigger.new) {
  if(cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == Account.sObjectType) {
    documents.put(cdl.ContentDocumentId, null);
    // Remember which links had accounts
    linksToCheck.add(cdl);
  }
}
// No links found, return early
if(documents.isEmpty()) {
  return;
}
// Get the documents
documents.putAll([SELECT FileType FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = :documents.keySet()]);
for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: linksToCheck) {
  // Now we know parent is an account, we can check for the file type
  if(documents.get(cdl.ContentDocumentId).FileType == 'SNOTE') {
    // Deduplicate using a map automatically. Faster than checking.
    accountsToUpdate.put(
      cdl.LinkedEntityId, 
      new Account(
        Id=cdl.LinkedEntityId, 
        Last_Note_Date__c=Date.today()
      )
    );
  }
}
update accountsToUpdate.values();
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code works for me.

```
trigger UpdatetField on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
Set<Id> accountId = new Set<Id>();
for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : Trigger.new) {
    if (cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == Account.sObjectType && cdl.ContentDocument.FileType == 'SNOTE') {
        accountId.add(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
    }
}

List<Account> accountUpdate = [SELECT Id, Last_Note_Date__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountId];

for (Account acc : accountUpdate) {
    acc.Last_Note_Date__c = System.now();
}

update accountUpdate;       }
```

I used "System.now()" in place of "date.today()".

Comment: `System.now()` gives you a `Datetime`, which would be a syntax error if you're trying to set a `Date` field (which is what I assume the field type is, based on the name). This also makes the same mistake of trying to fetch related data from records in a trigger context variable.

Comment: @DerekF  Sorry for missing on this and thanks for pointing in the right direction